# How to use a PHP if then else statements to change a logo depending on the url

Tags: php, image, wordpress, if-statement

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to assist with this.
I am looking to change a logo image depending on the page. For example:

For this page and all subsequent pages with this url:
**/occupational/wohl/**
/occupational/wohl/about-us
/occupational/wohl/another-page
/occupational/wohl/you-get-the-point

I would like to use logo2.png

Then for the rest of the site I would like to use logo1.png

This is simple for me to do using ASP because I am a little more familiar with it. There must be a way to do this with php. The site is a wordpress site.

Can anyone assist me with this issue?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and test for

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($url, "/occupational/wohl/") === 0) {
    echo '<a href="/" rel="home" id="logo" title="Wisconsin State Laboratory of Hygiene"></a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="/" rel="home" id="logo_ipsum" title="Ipsum Lorem"></a>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Frits, Forgive my ignorance, there is much room for improvement in my PHP knowledge. When I tried to add: <a href="/" rel="home" id="logo" title="Wisconsin State Laboratory of Hygiene"></a> (which is how the developer before me added the logo) I am getting an error. Am i supposed to place it in brackets? Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: do: `echo '<a href="/" rel="home" id="logo" title="Wisconsin State Laboratory of Hygiene"></a>'`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/occupational/wohl/") !== 0): ?>
   <a href="/" rel="home" id="logo" title="Wisconsin State Laboratory of Hygiene">
   <img src="/images/logo2.png"> 
   </a>
<? else: ?>
   <a href="/" rel="home" id="logo_ipsum" title="Ipsum Lorem">
   <img src="/images/logo1.png">
   </a>
<? endif; ?>
```